# how to remove null valve in grid store extjs

Tags: extjs, grid

[image]

The value becomes null as the store of Grid.json format is 
    {"struct_grid":[{"id":null,"struct_grid":null}]}

The Grid is

var grid1 = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {

```
border: false,
width: 'auto',
height: 300,
hideHeaders: true,
initComponent: function () {


    var config = {
        // store
        store: struct_grid_Store

        // column model
        , columns: [
              { text: "struct_grid", dataIndex: 'struct_grid' }
        ]

        // force fit
        , viewConfig: { forceFit: true, scrollOffset: 0 }


    }; // eo config object

    // apply config
    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
```

and Store is

```
var struct_grid_Store = new Ext.data.Store({
 reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
     fields: ['id', 'struct_grid'],
     root: 'struct_grid'
 }),
 proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url: '../../EicePackege/phpframework/DefStruct.php?mode=struct_grid',
 }),

 autoLoad: true,
 remoteSort: true
 });
```

Comment: Your image is too small to see anything. Also, your question is unclear. You're passing back null as a value, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: if all fields are null including `id`, then why you passing that data at all? I always filter data server side for null values and other stuff to reduce amount of code in client side

Comment: actually when passing back null as a value from php script it display blank row in grid how can i handle null value at client side in extjs that should not display in grid.!

Comment: @ TheRaaaZ is it required to handle all that at server side...?

Comment: Not required, but you'd need to implement a custom reader subclass to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not send a record back from server when it is not a record at all. Note that

```
{"id":null,"struct_grid":null}
```

is a valid JSON string so a valid JavaScript object and per default it will be a valid model instance. So the record will exist in the store and so it will be displayed. ExtJS does it all right. Yes you could handle this by tweaking the reader, but that is the wrong way.

If you want no record you should send none.

Comment: thanks for answer, i already apply it but i want to handle it from client side not server side..Please note this point..!

Comment: @ankitverma As I mentioned you will need to create your own reader for this. But let me tell that this is a dirty style of programming. You should not do such things!